How to fix these pixels in baking texture?
I used texture baking a lot in blender and this first time for this problem The edges between the two materials are pixelated.
I baking the texture 2K or 4K and no solution
used version 3.3.1 and 4.0.



so what is the issue here?

The edges between the two materials are pixelated.

We don't see two materials in your screenshot, only one material with one texture, all zoomed in. It's also normal to see pixels of a texture if you zoom enough. So please [edit] your question to provide more details about your situation, what you are trying to do exactly, what you expect to have and what you get instead. In addition, you can also share your file for us to better see what's going on.



This is the file. Is it normal for it to be pixelated like that? This is the first time I've seen it. It looks like I drew the texture in Paint.

Do the original materials use image textures? Because if material has low rez/low quality textures it doesn't matter if you bake in 2K/4K/8K if the source is low rez already it will remain that way after baking

No, it's not, it's a simple material like that.

Additionally to what Lauloque already wrote, you can optimize the UV layout. For example, align the UV faces to the pixel rows to minimize pixelation/aliasing.
Example 1, unwrap with Follow Active Quads option:


select a face (1)
make it a rectangle in the UV editor (menu UV > Align > ...) (2)
unwrap with Follow Active Quads option

The result will have minimal aliasing and stretching but a visible seam (3) if there is a pattern texture.
Example 2, alternative UV layout to get rid of the seam:


pin the UV verts (1) and unwrap it again to get this layout

The seam is gone, no visible aliasing, but there is more stretching and distortion (2).
Remember that you can separate UVs to have more than one UV island, which you can align and scale as required to suit your needs.

I think this will be the final solution, thank you for helping me.

So what you have here is a simple mesh with two materials assigned to different mesh parts, each being a Principled BSDF with different colors and other properties.
You are trying to bake the diffuse color from both materials into one texture. So what happens is for each pixel in the texture, the baking process will look from which material it belongs according to the UV unwrap, and from there sample the corresponding color. In this process of figuring out from which material to sample, there isn't an mixed answer, the pixel is always mostly from one face, so it will sample a color from only one material. Hence, the separation between the two will be pixel-perfect with no form of antialiasing.
One way to circumvent this is to bake at a higher resolution and then downsample, this is the most basic antialiasing method (MSAA).
Some addons such as Texttools have an option to do it for you.
That being said, it certainly doesn't help that your mesh's UV takes only a quarter of the whole UV space, you are effectively wasting 3/4 of your space, meaning each map wastes 3/4 of its computing time and its data load. And all the above is exacerbated since you have 4 times fewer pixels to deal with.

Using the menu UV > Pack Islands would automatically optimize that UV for you:

To give you an idea, this is what it looks like (in solid mode with a matcap for clarity) with a 1024px² texture with 4x MSAA (here done with Textools, but it would be the same with other tools or manually):


I will try this solution but I will unwrapping again to try to make the black line straight.
Thank you for your help.
